# How do I remove the Ubuntu option from the Windows 7 boot manager?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have Windows 7 as base operating system, and I have installed **Ubuntu 13.10** on it.

A few days later, my Windows 7 became corrupted. 
I installed Windows 7 again, but when I start the computer, there is still an option for Ubuntu in the boot manager. 
When I select the option for Ubuntu in the boot manager, it is not working(obviously due to data loss), because I installed Ubuntu in a partition in which window 7 is present. 
If I format the C(drive) as usual all data will be lost & I will lose ubuntu also but the problem is that option how can i trouble shoot that problem,so please tell me how to remove the option for it to install another copy of Ubuntu.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to separate some of the run-on sentences, here? I don't mean to be rude. However, sometimes a little effort to formatting a question helps us. It goes a long way toward getting the right answer, right away: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=run-on+sentence

Answer (score 2):

1. I would recommend that you backup your important data in `C:\` to another partition. (If you have 3 partitions, it would be the third partition. If only 2, the second partition).
2. Then reinstall Windows 7 on `C:\`.
3. Move back the important data to the initial location (in your case, it would be `C:\`), then format the duplicate Window 7 partition.
4. Reinstall Ubuntu to initial location. Ubuntu will install boot manager (grub).